# What does openpty() do? What does it mean that "the openpty() function finds an available pseudoterminal"?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, pty

I feel silly asking this ("just RTFM!") but I can't make sense of this man page. The [man page blurb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html) describing `openpty()`:

> The `openpty()` function finds an available pseudoterminal and returns
>   file descriptors for the master and slave in amaster and aslave. If
>   name is not NULL, the filename of the slave is returned in name. If
>   termp is not NULL, the terminal parameters of the slave will be set to
>   the values in termp. If winp is not NULL, the window size of the slave
>   will be set to the values in winp.

What does this mean?

My guess is that `openpty()` tries to find a pseudoterminal corresponding to a terminal emulator that is higher up in the process tree (some nth-parent, i.e. the terminal emulator that the program is running in, if any). However, the docs make it sound like `openpty()` just arbitrarily grabs something out of `/dev/pts`.

Also, what does "available" mean here? It seems like "available" has multiple meanings in the context of pseudoterminals (e.g. the kernel will let a terminal emulator create a pseudoterminal, a pseudoterminal can be read/written).

Comment: The kernel knows nothing about terminal emulators. Or, to put it another way, there is no system interface which you can use to say "I'm a terminal emulator, give me extra privileges." (For the obvious reason that if the privilege mattered, you could not trust a process' declaration.) A pseudoterminal is available if no  process has opened it. And `openpty` finds you one such (by arbitrarily grabbing one from the pool).

Comment: @rici It seems like terminal emulators cause entries to be added in `/dev/pty` and there isn't a fixed pool of existing pseudoterminals. There must be some way that terminal emulators can ask the kernel for a pty? (i.e. Even if the kernel doesn't give special blessing to terminal emulators, it provides some mechanism to be asked for a pty.)

Comment: Yes, it calls openpty. Or it opens ptys until it finds one not in use, which is effectively what openpty does.

Comment: @rici That makes sense. How does one open a pty to test if it's in use without using `openpty()` though?

Comment: Think `fork()`: you don't check if a PID is in use. you just call `fork()` to get an available PID.

Comment: @pynexj That's a good analogy. I think this has clicked for me but now I'm baffled by the chosen wording in the man page. It'd be very confusing, but not incorrect, to say that `fork()` "finds an available pid".

Comment: @praxeolitic: in the original BSD implementation, in which all devices (including pseudoterminals) were  created and named statically, you simply tried `open` on the list of known pty names (`/dev/ptyp0`, `/dev/ptyp1`, …) until you found one for which `open` succeeded.

Comment: @Praxeolitic I can't exactly remember, but before having `openpty()` we used loops over possible pseudoterm names and tried to open each, if not available failure is reported (can't remember which failure).

Comment: @Praxeolitic found it in `open(2)` "[EAGAIN] path specifies the slave side of a locked pseudo-terminal device."

Comment: @rici's comment would make a good addition to any answer here. If not for the history of `/dev/ttyp*` and `/dev/ptyp*`, we'd never have used the phrase "find an available pseudoterminal". The documentation here is very awkward if you expect it to only describe the newer `/dev/pts/` implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the docs make it sound like openpty() just arbitrarily grabs
>   something out of /dev/pts.

That's it.

> Also, what does "available" mean here? It seems like "available" has
>   multiple meanings in the context of pseudoterminals (e.g. the kernel
>   will let a terminal emulator create a pseudoterminal, a pseudoterminal
>   can be read/written).

Available simply means *that is not currently in use* by another process.

> > The openpty() function finds an available pseudoterminal and returns
> >     file descriptors for the master and slave in amaster and aslave. If
> >     name is not NULL, the filename of the slave is returned in name. If
> >     termp is not NULL, the terminal parameters of the slave will be set to
> >     the values in termp. If winp is not NULL, the window size of the slave
> >     will be set to the values in winp.
>
> What does this mean?

That you will receive in return all data necessary to manipulate the pseudo-term, its slave part, its master part and its filename.

Pseudo-terms emulate *real terminals* by implementing terminal input/output semantic. They are used in many contexts, to emulate a connected terminal (think about what happens when you log into a remote system via ssh for example) or to take control over some interactive program (design a GUI terminal in which a shell must run for example).

> I feel silly asking this ("just RTFM!")

Certainly not in that case, terminals and session management are very tricky things hard to handle at the beginning.

-----EDIT-----

*real terminals*. What was it? In early days (not the very early, the world of dinosaurs was more frightening) to connect to a system we used terminals, a simple device with a keyboard, a screen (no graphics) and some little hardware and software to manage a line which was plugged into one of computer's plug. Thus there was a need, in the OS to manage all those input/outputs from the terminal: echoing typed chars to screen when needed, buffering input/output to be able to delete chars on command lines, etc. That OS part was managed through terminal drivers represented as devices like `/dev/ttyXXX`. One such physical device, one OS terminal device.

Nowadays such physical devices doesn't exists anymore, except in some special cases, like servers consoles (I mean the one connected directly to the machine!, or your screen at boot time when all those weird messages appears in text mode, etc). We now connect to OSes through many different *virtual* things (todays computer world is about *virtuality*), like GUI-terminal which emulates the behavior of a physical terminals. Then both ends part of the old physical line are represented in a pseudo-terminal which come in two parts: master and slave. The *slave* represent the old part that was in the OS that the application sees. The *master* represent the plug of the old physical line so that it is now offered as a software that let's you write an application that is able to take the input/output control over that *virtual line* and behave like a *real terminal*.

Comment: One other interesting point is that many programmers today have never used a "real terminal". I'm not even sure that the phrase is meaningful, although serial ports still exist and embedded programming still uses them. Is a Linux console a "real terminal"? (And how many people use a Linux console, I wonder.)

Comment: You should add something about the historical context from your comments to this answer. It helps newcomers like me to know that the documentation wording here is due to historical reasons rather than something deeply profound.

Comment: @rici Yes a Linux console, I mean not the GUI console, the console at boot time for example, is a *real terminal*. Yes those concepts are hard to handle...

Comment: @Praxeolitic Added some historical things about terminals.