# How to respond to any command line prompts in C

Tags: c, git, command-prompt, expect

I'm trying to automate the process of doing

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push origin master
```

In C.

I've already done a bash script with [Expect](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/expect)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

HOME="/home/prxvvy"
filename="$HOME/Documents/github_creds.txt"

username=`awk 'NR==1' $filename`
password=`awk 'NR==3' $filename`

echo "Enter a message for commit:"
read message
expect <<EOS
spawn git add .
expect
spawn git commit -m "$message"
expect
spawn git push origin master
expect "Username for 'https://github.com':"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password for 'https://$username@github.com':"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
EOS
```

So how would I "send" the requested data when the "Username for 'https://github.com':" prompt comes up, with C?

PS: I don't want to use any git api or something as I did in the bash script

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish tbh. What is `expect`?

Comment: A small comment about the expect code: after `spawn git add` and `spawn git commit`, use `expect eof`. Even better, use `exec` instead of `spawn` since you don't need to interact with those git commands at all.

Comment: it's not easy with C code. you can call your Expect script in C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer #1: you can't.  The problem here has nothing to do with Git per se.  Programs that read passwords from humans make sure they're not talking to other programs, by making sure they're using the human `/dev/tty` interface.  So your program can't push a password into another program.

Answer #2: you can, but you must re-implement `expect`.  The expect program tricks other programs into thinking they are talking to a human.  This is fairly complicated and involves opening a "pseudo tty" from the control side, initializing it properly on the dependent side, and doing any OS-level operations required to make it become the `/dev/tty` that other programs will get when they open it.  Then, having done all this song and dance (some of which is available in some libraries via [`openpty`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47806759/1256452) or similar), you can then run a program.  You then must implement the rest of `expect` to read data coming through the control side of the pty pair, interpret it to figure out what the program is doing, and feed it data.

(Note that if all you want to do is run `git push` without having to enter a password, Git can invoke authentication methods that do this.  Git does not have *its own built in* authentication: it relies on *credential helpers* when using `https` and ssh's credentialing and authentication systems when using `ssh`.  So if you're using `https://` for your URL, you want to configure a credential helper to do the job, and if you're using `ssh://` for your URL, you want to configure ssh.  You said that's not what you're interested in, though.)

Comment: What i'm gonna say might look newbie but I looked at Expect source code and it's all written in C and it's treated as an interpreter in execs, does it not include functions to use in C or something?

Comment: It is indeed written in C. It's not very *portable* C though, unless it gets to rely on something like openpty().

Comment: Expect does provide a library of functions which can be called from C - https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/libexpect.3.html - this will be a lot more work to use than the `expect` program though.